# DFA for strings not containing aaa as substring and must contain aa as sufix

Tags: automata

Given language L={ w ∈ {a, b, c}* | w does not contain aaa as substring and w must contain aa as sufix}.

I tested this words:

aa correct
aaa fail
baa correct
caa correct
abaa correct
acaa correct
accccccaa correct
aaacaa fail
bbaaa fail
abcaa correct
aabcaa correct

My DFA:

[image]

There's some case I'm missing?

Comment: I dont think this is a DFA , as you also need an arrow from $Q_2$ in case of a. i.e leading to a stranded state $Q_3$

Comment: Why its not a DFA?  and an a from q2 to q3 would be ilegal

Comment: It would not be illegal if $Q_3$ were to be stranded menaing from $Q_3$ when reading a,b,c you only stay in $Q_3$ and $Q_3$ should not be an accept state. It is not a DFA because $\delta$ does not define a function that is defined on every tuple of  $Q x \sum$ , depending on how you define it. At least thats how we defined it in a class i took.